# Сайдбар SublimeText3

Tags: javascript, html, css, sublime-text-3

Здравствуйте, возник вопрос:  При включении сайдбара в ST3 он сворачивается после перехода в другое окно или же просто при написании кода через несколько секунд.

Comment: Возможно у Вас какой-то плагин делает это... https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Auto%20Hide%20Sidebar

Comment: Спасибо, проверю.